# Is this kind of email formal or beneficial to use in a submitted manuscript?

Tags: publications, conference, writing, paper-submission, writing-style

Is this kind of email formal or beneficial or even acceptable to use in a manuscript: yours@xxx.edu? yours@xxx.edu or authorname@xxx.edu? which is better? can it increase the acceptance rate?

Comment: What's the difference between yours@xxx.edu and authorname@xxx.edu?  What is "yours" supposed to represent?

Comment: I mean, I have two candidate emails, exactly yours@abc.edu and lexintonave@abc.edu. Which is better to use for that  in the manuscript?

Answer (score 10):

The email address you specify has zero bearing on whether or not your paper is accepted. Having an easy-to-remember, stable email address is helpful because it ensures fewer problems when sending mail to you in the future.

Comment: I occasionally get emails from students from some quite unprofessional/embarrassing email addresses (e.g. mickeymouse@web.de). Some of these may trigger a spam filter. Other than that it may raise some eyebrows, and you may feel embarrassed after a couple of years when that email address is still linked to your name. But anything reasonably professional should be just fine.

Comment: @MaartenBuis Will exact yours@web.de be fine?

Comment: It’s a bit precious, but it’s not awful per se.

Comment: It is not awful, but I tend to prefer the addresses from your institution.

Comment: @MaartenBuis My instituition currently allows for free registration.